What shapes can roll down tailor-made curves, without jumping off or behaving chaotically?
Background
It is well-known that the disk can roll down various curves, including the straight line and the Brachistochrone curve. The latter is the curve along which both a point rolls down the fastest. The disk rolls fastest along a modified version of the Brachistochrone. Various variations and generalizations of this problem have been described here, for instance.
What I am interested in are different types of shapes that roll down various curves. For instance, I wonder along what curve the ellipse rolls down the fastest. It turns out that this is a difficult problem. In fact, it may even be the case that the ellipse cannot roll down any curve without eventually jumping and moving chaotically.
In a series of videos by Morphocular, it is described how to find the curve along which any two-dimensional shape can roll along horizontally in a smooth manner. These curves are called roulettes. In case of the ellipse, it turns out that its roulette is a sine curve. One can find a suitable curve for horizontal motion for any shape. Below, I depict three examples (this is a still from one of the videos by Morphocular).
$\hspace{4cm}$
Question
However, I don't know yet which shapes can roll down, without jumping off at some point, or behave chaotically. For instance, one could try to roll a square down a parabola. However, it will quickly lose contact with the parabola, and start behaving chaotically.
Even in the combinations of the shapes and curves depicted above, the roulettes, the shapes can probably only roll along the curve horizontally. But if we tried tilting the curves so the shapes roll down, they probably jump off at some point. (See, for instance, the combination of the ellipse and the sine curve here, which is a roulette - Claude Chaunier expresses doubt the ellipse can roll down, although we haven't found a proof yet).
To make things precise (as per Will Sawin's comment), were are considering a shape following Newtonian physics under (1) gravity, a constant downward force on the center of mass of the shape, (2) a normal force at the contact point strong enough to prevent the shape from crossing the curve, (3) a friction force at the contact point strong enough to prevent the shape from slipping. I am looking for combinations of shapes and curves for which the shape rolls down the curve, where the shape is neither allowed to jump off the curve, nor behave chaotically.
Of course, one can consider modifications of a circle to think of 'new' shapes that can roll down various curves. For instance, if one makes a circular hole in the center of the circle (so one effectively obtains an annulus), then this different shape can roll down as well, without losing contact with the curve - which can be a downward straight line or a Brachistochrone in this case.
What I find more interesting are shapes that actually have a different outside boundary. So my question is:

What shapes can roll down a tailor-made curve without jumping off or behaving chaotically, and how does one mathematically describe these curves? How do these curves relate to the shape?

Notes:

This may be a relevant question.
I've also asked this question on MSE.


"In a smooth manner" is rather vague. Must the shape's center of gravity remain at the same y-value during the kind of rolling that you prefer?

Also: Where you write "What I find more interesting, are shapes that actually have a different outside boundary" I have no idea what you mean. Any two non-congruent shapes have a "different outside boundary".

@DanielAsimov If that were the case, the shape couldn't roll down, no?

@DanielAsimov I just wanted to point out that I don't consider an annulus an interesting example, because the outside boundary is the same as a circle's. And for that shape it is clear there are multiple curves along which it can roll down

It would be better to edit the question for clarity. But again, I have no idea what you mean by a curve that it "can roll down". Almost any down-sloping curve is one that almost any shape "can roll down".

@DanielAsimov If you have any suggestions to phrase the question more clearly - please let me know

Maybe if you reread my comments you will be able to clarify your question.

@DanielAsimov I do write that the shape cannot jump off. If you were to try to roll, say, a square shape down a parabola, it will quickly lose contact with the parabola and behave chaotically

To try to make things precise, you are considering a shape following Newtonian physics under (1) gravity, a constant downward force on the center of mass of the shape, (2) a normal force at the contact point strong enough to prevent the shape from crossing the curve, (3) a friction force at the contact point strong enough to prevent the shape from slipping, and the question is whether the shape ever leaves the curve? Jumping off the curve and chaotic behavior are not necessarily related - rolling could potentially be chaotic without jumps, or jump without being chaotic.

@WillSawin Right, that's what I mean. Good point about jumping off and chaotic behavior not necessarily being related. For the purposes of this question, neither is allowed.

Not clear to me whether you have defined "chaos" in your context.
